# How do I turn on experimental ingestion on a standalone network?

Tags: stellar-core

I'm trying to turn on experimental ingestion on my standalone network so that I can try out the strict-send path finding endpoint, which doesn't seem to be implemented with the non-experimental pathfinder. I set my history-archive-urls to "http://localhost:11626." My history archives definitely exist.

I'm running into this error:

[31mERRO[0m[2019-11-19T11:56:35.642-08:00] Error getting the latest ledger sequence: could not get root HAS: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

I'm running v0.23.0 of horizon, with v12.0.0 of stellar-core, built in Windows.

Comment: Looks like my archive url should be the path to the actual location of the archive folder on my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, history-archive-urls should be set to the location of the archive on the file system, with the url-scheme: "file://"